# MongoDB: one big document or more than one collection

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB and I'm not sure how to define my schema.

I have a user's table and every user activity is logged. My question is, should I have just one user collection with all actions embedded:

```
User: {
     id: 1,
     name: 'John',
     log: [{
        activity: {
           action: 'logged in...'
        },
        activity: {
           action: 'logged in...'
        },
        activity: {
           action: 'password reset...'
        }
}]
```

}

or should I have two separate collections: users and userlog?

```
User: {
     id: 1,
     name: 'John'
}


UserLog: {
     id: 1,
     action: 'logged in...',
     userid: 2
}
```

My only worry about option 1 is that the document might end up being too big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing arrays that grow frequently and without bound, especially if you might want to index any field in the array like `action`, is a Bad Idea. Even without knowing too much about this use case, I think it's safe to say that user history information should be in a separate collection, with each audited event as its own document.

See this Ask Asya post about [large arrays](http://askasya.com/post/largeembeddedarrays) for the reasons, but basically the documents will have to be totally rewritten a lot as they grow, creating a lot more I/O than normal in-place updates, and maintaining indexes gets very expensive with large, growing arrays.

Answer (score 0):

It depens. From [mongo docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/#large-number-of-collections)

> In certain situations, you might choose to store information in several collections rather than in a single collection.

Also consider that the maximum BSON document size is 16 megabytes, so if your documents tend to grow considerably, it's better to have more than one collection.

Comment: Growing documents are also bad for performance reasons. When an update causes a document to grow, it sometimes becomes necessary to move it to a different place in the database file which can take a while.